# It has been a month since the final interview. Should I contact the interviewer for application status? Interviewer is a client of current employer!

Tags: job-offer, feedback

I had an interview with a client of my current employer. At the end of the final stage interview, I was advised to expect a reply within seven days. I never heard anything back for almost two weeks, so I decided to chase it via the HR person who organised the interview. Someone else from the recruitment team called a few days later. After apologising for the delay in getting back to me, she asked me about pay expectations. It turned out my current salary was higher than what they were willing to pay for the new role. I explained that I am prepared to take a pay drop for the right opportunity. After a bit of discussion, she agreed to send me details of the full package by close of play.

Its been another ten days since last phone call but I haven't heard anything back from HR. **I work with hiring manager regularly so should I ask her/him about my application's status directly?**. The hiring manager and I are not based at the same office.

Comment: `Interviewer is a client of current employer!` I would make sure there isn't a conflict of interest.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for taking time out of your commitments to answer this question. I much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll convert my comment into an answer.

First of all, it sounds like HR and recruitment are having a hard time with your acquisition. This isn't very unusual but it is rather annoying for the candidate so I understand your concern.

I don't think it would be wrong to contact the recruitment and/or HR and seeing if everything is going well. It is likely they are just really wanting to triple check everything, i.e. your skills, interviews, etc. Also screening can be a lengthy process.

**However, I would *strongly* advise you to NOT contact the hiring manager.** This would be seen as a conflict of interest and it could really ruin your opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to focus on your question and not the parts concerning your pay decrease and that interaction.

> Someone else from the recruitment team called a few days later

You should continue your chain of communication with this person.   This individual has already set themselves as your point of contact.   Send an email, and then 48 hrs later follow up with a phone call if you have a contact number.

It's not a guarantee sign that they don't want to continue with hiring, just doesn't look good with that much time lapse and no communication.

> I work with hiring manager regularly so should I ask her/him about my
>   application's status directly?.

Keep that relationship about your current work, not your job prospects would be my suggestion.